# How to determine the screen which has taskbar using java swing?

Tags: java, swing, window, multiscreen

I have some troubles with determining the screen with taskbar(if there are a lot of screens)
I need to provide my application with the behavior described below.
User opens my java swing application and minimizes it (the icon is shown on taskbar).
The user closes the application: right click on the icon of taskbar, then close.
I want my app to show confirmation dialog on that screen where the taskbar is located.
So I used showOptionDialog of JOptionPane. If I invoke it with parentComponent set to null the dialog is shown on the main screen, not on screen which has taskbar.
That's why I need some solution to identify a screen with taskbar and show dialog there.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 java.awt.SystemTray.isSupported();
```

this can help you.

You can also check the object received by

```
 getSystemTray()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But SystemTray says nothing about screen.